# Manifest error (Duplication of elements) while combining two functions

Tags: android, google-maps, android-manifest, manifest

I have combined 2 functions: nearby locations and friend finder. As a result it's showing me this manifest error:

[image]

In this second pic, you will see that manifest is showing duplication error:

[image]

How to get rid of this error?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note that [you should not post code/errors as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question); instead, copy the code/error and format it as a code block. This will make it much easier for people to review your code and answer your question.

Comment: I downvoted because: [Image of Code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode), [Image of Exception](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/)

Answer (score 0):

You have two meta-data tags with the same name and probably the same value. It looks like one hard-codes the value string and the other uses your string resource file. You should be able to just delete one of them. I.e. just comment out lines 48-51 in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: one API in metadata is google places API for nearby location, the other one is google maps API for friend finder, when i delete one of the metadata, the compilation error occurs because one of the two functions will get affected